# Display value in Date field irrespective of date format

Tags: apache-flex

I have an `mx:DateField` in my Flex UI that has a `formatString="dd.mm.yyyy"` attached to it. However, the initial value for that field may not be in the format specified/defined for the DateField (due to legacy reasons). So, currently, if I just set that value (`text`) on the DateField, the field is shown empty. I think because it fails to accept the value in a format different than what's configured.

I need to (somehow) be able to display the incoming value in the date field. Is that possible? If yes, how?

P.S. : The incoming value's format will not be known, so I cannot transform it to my desired format :(.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the value into a date first, then use the dateField's dateToString method to set the text.

Comment: but the point is that I don't have the format, so I cannot parse it into a legible Date.

Comment: This is the best you're going to get http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#parse() without knowing the format.